# Cómo eliminar un elemento de un array sin que deje NULL en la posición que estaba

Tags: javascript

Estoy eliminando un elemento de un array pero al eliminarlo deja *null* en la posición en la que estaba y me interesa que no deje nada.

¿Qué le debo agregar?

```js
let x = [

{
id: "2021"
},
{
id: "2022"
}

];


function remove() {

delete x[0];

document.write(JSON.stringify(x));

}
```

```html
<button onclick="remove()">Remover</button>
```

Comment: con delete quitas la referencia en la memoria del elemento con un console.log verías que   es undefined la longitud del array se mantiene si usas splice el array muta varia su longitud si usas filter obtenes un nuevo array con los valores que te interesen}

Answer (score 1):

funcion [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

```js
let x = [

{
id: "2021"
},
{
id: "2022"
}

];


function remove() {

x.splice(0, 1);

document.write(JSON.stringify(x));

}
```

```html
<button onclick="remove()">Remover</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que utilizar el método [**`splice()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) para que elimines un rango de elementos basado en un índice inicial y final, para este caso, partimos desde la primera posición de tu array:

```
x.splice(0, 1);
```

Tu código resultaría así:

```js
let x = [
  {
    id: '2021',
  },
  {
    id: '2022',
  },
];

function remove() {
  x.splice(0, 1);
  document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="remove()">Remover</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Todos hablan de usar splice, así que te dejo un pequeño ejemplo usando [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) en vez de splice

```js
let x = 
[
  {
id: "2021"
  },
  {
id: "2022"
  }
];


function remove() {
  /* Con filter podemos pasarle una función en la que especificamos qué elementos
   * queremos conservar (aquellos para los que la función devuelve true) y cuales no,
   * de esta manera podemos filtrar de manera mucho más detallada que usando splice
   */
  const filtered = x.filter(el => el.id >= "2022");
  document.write(JSON.stringify(filtered));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="remove()">Remover</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Con delete quitas la referencia en la memoria del elemento

> **El método slice()** devuelve una copia de una parte del array dentro de
> un nuevo array empezando por inicio hasta fin (fin no incluido). El
> array original no se modificará.
>
> array.slice(arg1, arg2); --> **arg1:Índice donde empieza la extracción**
> **arg2:Indice que marca el fin de la extraccion**
> slice(1,4) extrae desde el segundo elemento
> hasta el cuarto (los elementos con índices 1, 2, y 3).el ultimo no
> estara incluido

```js
let x = [

  {
    id: "2021"
  },
  {
    id: "2022"
  }

];


function remove() {
  let y = x.slice(0, 1)


  document.write('No muta :' + JSON.stringify(x) + '--->');

  document.write('Nuevo array:' + JSON.stringify(y));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="remove()">Remover</button>
```